# uncaught syntax error unexpected token '> ' occur in <script type="module"

Tags: reactjs

I'm using this line of code to include the react component

```
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/react/16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="module" src="invoice.js"></script>
```

Part of the code

```
  for (let i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
    td.push(<tr key={i}>
        <td valign="top" align="center">{i+1} of {total_package}</td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">{i+1}<br />
            &nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;<br />
            &nbsp;<br /></td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">Brown Package</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{desc[i].value}</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{qty[i].value}</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">kg</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{weight[i].value}</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center"><br />
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">{row_total[i].value}</td>
    </tr>);
```

but if i use `<script type="text/babel" src="invoice.js"></script>`, the error is gone but there is another error

```
invoice.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:14
    at i (babel.min.js:24)
    at r (babel.min.js:24)
    at e.src.n.<computed>.l.content (babel.min.js:24)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24)
```

so i can't use import statement:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';
```

How to make them both exist without conflict?
invoice.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//const { Component } = React;
//const { render } = ReactDOM;


//const { ReactToPrint } = Component.ReactToPrint;

//const { Button } = ReactBootstrap.Button;
//const { ButtonGroup } = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup;


const $ = jQuery;

class Invoice extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
                    refNo : document.getElementsByName('refNo')[0].value,
                    senderAddress : document.getElementsByName('senderAddress')[0].value,
                    recipientName : document.getElementsByName('recipientName')[0].value,
                    recipientAddress : document.getElementsByName('recipientAddress')[0].value,
                    recipientCity : document.getElementsByName('recipientCity')[0].value,
                    country : document.getElementById('country').innerHTML,
                    ManCountry : '',
                    showWayBillInput : false,
                    load : false
                 };


    //recipientName
    //alert(document.getElementsByName('refNo')[0].value);

  }

  componentWillMount(){

  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ManCountry: this.getManCountry()});

  }

  getDate = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    return today;

  }

  getManCountry = () => {

      var country_of_manufacturer = "";
      var country_of_manufacturer_array = [];
      var num = document.getElementById("container").childElementCount;
      var prev = "";
      for (var i=0;i<num;i++) {
        country_of_manufacturer = document.getElementsByName("country_of_manufacturer["+ i +"]")[0].value; 

        if (country_of_manufacturer != prev) {
            country_of_manufacturer_array.push(country_of_manufacturer);
        }
        prev = country_of_manufacturer;

      }

      /*for (var j=0;j<country_of_manufacturer_array.length;j++) {
        console.log(country_of_manufacturer);
      }*/

      //console.log(country_of_manufacturer_array.join());

      return country_of_manufacturer_array.join();
  }

  wayBillOpen = () => {
      //$("#dialog").dialog("open");
      this.setState({
        showWayBillInput: true
      });

  }

  wayBillClose = () => {
      //$("#dialog").dialog("open");
      this.setState({
        showWayBillInput: false
      });

      var temp = $('#waybill').val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
      //alert(temp);
      $('#numbers').html(temp);

  }

  loaditems = () => {
      this.setState({load: true});
  }

  createTd = () => {
      let td = [];
      var desc = $('#items_div #desc');
      var qty = $('#items_div #qty');
      var weight = $('#items_div #weight');
      var row_total = $('#items_div #row_total');
      var total_package = desc.length;
      $('#total_package').html(total_package);

      var total_weight = 0;
      var total_value = 0;      
      for (let j = 0; j < weight.length; j++) {
        total_weight += parseFloat(weight[j].value);
      }
      $('#total_weight').html(total_weight);
      for (let k = 0; k < row_total.length; k++) {
        total_value += parseFloat(row_total[k].value);
      }
      $('#total_value').html(total_value);
      var date = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0];
      $('#datetime').html(date);

      for (let i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
        td.push(<tr key={i}>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{i+1} of {total_package}</td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{i+1}<br />
                &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp;<br />
                &nbsp;<br /></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">Brown Package</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">{desc[i].value}</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">{qty[i].value}</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">kg</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">{weight[i].value}</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"><br />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">{row_total[i].value}</td>
        </tr>);

      }

      return td;
  }

  renderTableRows() {
      if (this.state.load == true) {


        //alert(desc[0].value);
        return (this.createTd())
      }
  }

  render() {
    const mystyle = {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
      padding: "10px",
      fontFamily: "Arial"
    };
    return (
        <table bordercolor="#000000" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" width="600" border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Date of Export:</span><br />
                    <span id="">{this.getDate()}</span>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="5">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Export References:
                    </span><br />
                    <span id="refNo">{this.state.refNo}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Shipper/Exporter (complete name and address):</span><br />
                    <span id="senderAddress">{this.state.senderAddress}</span>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="5">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Recipient (complete name and address):</span><br />
                    <span id="recipientName">{this.state.recipientName}</span><br />
                    <span id="recipientAddress">{this.state.recipientAddress}</span><br />
                    <span id="recipientCity">{this.state.recipientCity}</span><br />
                    <span id="country">{this.state.country}</span><br />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Country of export:</span><br />
                    <span id="export">Hong Kong</span>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="5" rowSpan="3">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Importer - if other than recipient<br />
                    <nobr>(complete name and address):</nobr>
                    </span><p>As Above</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                <span className="contentsmall">Country of manufacture:</span><br />
                {this.state.ManCountry}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                <span className="contentsmall">Country of ultimate destination:</span>&nbsp;<br />
                USA</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" colSpan="4">
                <span className="contentsmall">Federal Express International Air Waybill No.:</span>&nbsp;<br />
                <input type="button" value="+" onClick={this.wayBillOpen}/>
                <div id="numbers"></div>
                <div className="main">
                    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Form" style={{display: this.state.showWayBillInput ? 'block' : 'none' }}>

                        <label>Waybill numbers:</label><br />
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="waybill"></textarea>
                        <input type="button" value="Close" onClick={this.wayBillClose} />
                    </div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>            
            </td>
            <td valign="top" colSpan="5"><span className="contentsmall">Currency:</span>&nbsp;<br />
            USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Marks/Nos</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">No. of<br />pkgs</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Type<br />
                of packaging</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Full Description<br />of goods</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Qty</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Units of<br />
                measure</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Weight</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Unit Value</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Total<br />
                Value</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {this.renderTableRows()}
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Total<br />
                    No. of<br />
                    Pkgs
                    </span>&nbsp;<br />
                </td>
                <td colSpan="4"></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <span className="contentsmall">Total<br />
                    Weight</span>&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                <span className="contentsmall">Total<br />
                    Invoice<br />
                    Value</span>&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"><div id="total_package"></div></td>
                <td colSpan="4"></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"><div id="total_weight"></div></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
                <td valign="top" align="center"><div id="total_value"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" colSpan="8">
                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colSpan="2">
                        <span className="contentsmall">I declare all the information contained in this invoice to be true and correct</span>&nbsp;<br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><span className="contentsmall">Signature of shipper/exporter (type name and title and sign)</span><p>tester<br /><br /><br /><br />
                    _____________________________________</p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top"><span className="contentsmall"><br /><br />Date:</span><p><div id="datetime"></div><br />
                    ___________</p>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left">
                <span className="contentsmall">Tick<br /></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="9">
                    <button onClick={this.loaditems}>Load the line items</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Invoice />, document.getElementById("right_container"));
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?. why are you pushing html elements to array?

Comment: `invoice.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` where's this line?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yes

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel first line

Comment: @hkguile But it isn't in the post.

Comment: invoice.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined is the error, cause by  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';

Comment: The first line is an `import`, but you have an error message saying that the `require` value doesn't exist. And which error message is "gone" when you switch to babel?

Comment: i mean the first error is gone if switch to babel. the first error is stated in title.

Comment: Yes, partially. The full message should be in the post. You didn't post enough to make a minimal verifiable and repeatable example. But, I will take a shot in the dark: your `td.push(<tr key={i}> ... );` is giving you an error because you have `(<` and that's a syntax error. I presume you're trying to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). In that case, you should do ``td.push(`<tr key=${i}> ... `);``. Notice the `${...}` syntax.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel i've tried your solution, but it is the same.

Comment: @hkguile That means you have more stuff somewhere else, which isn't in the question. Please provide it. At the moment, all we can do is guess. Which isn't going to get you any answers. Please provide a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And all the error messages you get, all **in the question**.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel i posted a full source

Comment: Try removing those `import ...`, use `<script type="text/babel" src="invoice.js"></script>` and include the babeljs file before that `<script type="text/babel" ...>`. Also, rename your file to `.jsx` or check this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the reason i try to change to using "module" from "babel", i can't import "import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';", if change to use "babel", how can i use ReactToPrint ?

Comment: You don't. According to the examples and https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx, you don't need that. Just follow the documentation on how to use JSX.

Comment: but how to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print if import statement is not allowed?